# Facebook comment with tabular data, how to align two columns

Tags: html, facebook

I would like to present a list of items in a Facebook comment that includes an amount, a name and then a price.  Ideally I would like for this to be relatively aligned.

I know I can not change the font display of Facebook to a monospace font to have it align perfectly, but what I'm wondering is if I could preformat the data that I would display in a webpage so it would copy to a Facebook comment in at least a roughly aligned format.

Ex [image: Facebook Layout]

It presently copies as the top images (blocked in red)
and through manual manipulation I am able to quasi format it to align "better" like the block in green.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Here is a copy of the data as presented in my webpage.

```
 3 Abandoned Outpost           $0.15    
 9 Abandoned Outpost           $0.15    
 2 Abbey Gargoyles             $0.25    
 3 Abbey Gargoyles             $0.25    
 2 Abbey Gargoyles             $0.00    
 3 Abbey Gargoyles             $0.00    
 1 Abbey Matron (No Hood)      $0.15
```

Comment: Well, you could post an image instead...

Comment: @Alex I am trying to add functionality for users, and I will be having the "Name" also act as a hyperlink, so unfortunately a picture wouldn't really work.